# Importing bootstrap with rails, errror

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, import

I am new to programming and have been working on developing my first basic application. I have been having the same problem for over 24 hrs now.

I am receiving this error when I try to reload my apps homepage after installing bootstrap and importing it...

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#home
```

I installed the bootstrap gem and ran bundle install...

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

I then created a new css document in my stylesheets folder and titled it custom.css.scss

from there I imported bootstrap...

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I saved the file and when I refreshed the page I received the error message I listed in the beginning.

Below is the error message that I receive. It's telling me the error occurs around line 5. I tried saving the file as .scss instead of .css.scss, but the problem persisted.

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/jackburum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
  (in /Users/jackburum/Documents/rails_projects/omrails/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3:     <head>
4:       <title>Omrails</title>
5:      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:     </head>
```

Comment: what's the content of your custom bootstrap file?

Comment: I believe the file extension should be custom.scss then it creates custom.css

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall, not necessarily. I've used this gem and I call my file bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss

Comment: @user2091331, show us your custom.css.scss and more information on the error? Do you have a line number?

Comment: Ahh thanks @Leito I'm more familiar with LESS. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding

```
require "bootstrap-sass"
```

to application.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try to bundle your project gems into the project folder itself.

`bundle install --path .bundle`

I am having same problem, i found solution from [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/270).